# Make file location parameterized based on user-entered values in log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, properties-file

In my `log4j.properties` file I have a line for log file location:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=<file path>.log
```

I want to set this based on user provided path during runtime. How do I do that with Log4J?

Also, if I switch to Logback, how do I configure `logback.xml` to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

In Log4J you can use a variable like so:

```
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${log.file}.log
```

You would then supply a value for `log.file` as a Java system property when launching your application. For example:

```
java -Dlog.file=/some/path/app MyApp
```

This would result in the following derived value for `log4j.appender.logfile.File`:

```
 /some/path/app.log
```

Logback provides the same feature. Here's an example, using Logback's XML configuration:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>${log.file}.log</file>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

You would define the `log.dir` address when running your application like so:

```
java -Dlog.file=/some/path/app MyApp
```

More details [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingProps).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added the following line in logback.xml configuration which worked perfectly for me since I don't want the user to specify the log.file as a property each time they run the application :-

`<property file="${properties.file}" />`

Comment: The user then specifies the location of the properties file (which contains several properties) during runtime `java -Dproperties.file=<path_to_properties_file> ...`